# Two abstracts with different names in LateX

Tags: latex, abstract-class, naming

I am using a LateX template for my PhD thesis which is available via this link: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/blob/master/Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls 
I wish to include two abstracts for the request of the University. One with the name "Abstract" and one with the name "Lay Summary". But I am having trouble changing the title in the second abstract. The abstract is a tex file starting with the following lines:

```
\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}
```

The documentclass is a custom defined environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
```

I tried this code in the second abstract before the \begin{abstract} line with an error message: "! LaTeX Error: \abstractname undefined".

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Lay Summary}
```

And even if it would change the title I do not need it to be changed globally just for the second time. I need to have the second abstract before the numbered content, ideally after the first abstract. Is there any suggestion what to try?

Comment: I suggest that you delete your question and post it on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should actually first search on TeX SE: there are various questions/answers that are related (but AFAICT, the answer depends on the documentclass, so you'll have to find how it defines the abstract name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got, say quite easily, a tested solution.

In my folder, I saved your custom documentclass file as `docclass.cls`.

In the same folder, I saved and compiled my [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)/main `.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{docclass}

\newenvironment{laysummary} {
  \cleardoublepage
  \setsinglecolumn
  \chapter*{\centering \Large Lay Summary}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
First.
\end{abstract}

\begin{laysummary}
Second.
\end{laysummary}

\chapter{Chapter}
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

This produces the output you wanted to achieve with Abstract **and** Lay Summary:

[image: Abstract followed by Lay Summary]

Notice that the key thing is in the lines:

```latex
\newenvironment{laysummary} {
  \cleardoublepage
  \setsinglecolumn
  \chapter*{\centering \Large Lay Summary}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
}
```

that I took from lines 1105-1121 of your custom documentclass:

```latex
\newenvironment{abstract} {
\ifPHD@abstract
% Separate abstract as per Student Registry guidelines
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \setsinglecolumn
  \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1em} \@author} \par}
  \end{center}
\else
% Normal abstract in the thesis
  \cleardoublepage
  \setsinglecolumn
  \chapter*{\centering \Large Abstract}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\fi
}
```

I did not remove or even modify these latter **inside** the documentclass file, I edited a copy of it that I then pasted in the main tex file. If you want to keep your main tex file cleaner, my six lines defining `laysummary` environmemt may be pasted at the end of the documentclass cls file instead.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the documentclass file, I would try the following in the second abstract file:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@title}{Lay Summary}
\makeatother
\begin{abstract}
 ...
\end{abstract}
```

but no guarantees.

Comment: I tried to compile your code but the Abstract name does not change, despite no errors or warnings. I added an answer after compiling a test file.