# Changing University name, thesis title e.a. for abstract in different language

Tags: latex, tex

I need to write two different abstracts in my thesis in german and in english. The German one works fine and by using the \begin{otherlanguage} command, the abstract name itself changes to english. But furthermore  I need to use an english tilte, university name, faculty name and company name for the second abstract. I tried using \renewcommand but it does not change the title in the output file, which is still german.

I found packages for multiple titles (\titling), but that is not working for the university name and so on.

Thank you in advance

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, english, ngerman,]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\thesistitle{Title in German}
\university{University Title in German}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname}
German German German
\end{abstract}


\begin{otherlanguage}{english}

\renewcommand{\thesistitle}{Title in English}
\renewcommand{\university}{University Title in English}

\begin{abstract}
English English English
\end{abstract}

\end{otherlanguage}
```

Comment: Does this help? [Two abstracts with different names in LateX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174870/two-abstracts-with-different-names-in-latex)

Comment: I came across this one already. Unfortunately not helping with the renaming problem

Answer (score 1):

[image: mustermensch]

```latex
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)

\documentclass[11pt, english, ngerman,openany]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\thesistitle{Wombat} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Gerald Giraffe} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{Uni der Zootiere} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{Institut der Angewandten Tierpflegeranalyse} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\begin{document}



\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}


\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@title}{Capybara}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\univname}{Univerity of Zoo Animals}
\renewcommand{\deptname}{Institute for applied Something}
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have, neither know the package MastersDoctoralThesis. 
If it includes the babel package, you can use iflang to test the active language.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\IfLanguageName{german}{
German German German
}{
English English English
}
\end{document}
```

If your document class does not include the babel language, you can do something similar by defining a macro and testing its value with the ifthen package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\mylanguage{german}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mylanguage}{german}}{
German German German
}{
English English English
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The language settings are working fine, its just the renaming of the \thesistitle and \university which is not functioning. But thanks for the suggestion!